# Error when calling subroutines "Expected Variable or Procedure, not Module."

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a subroutine that will call one of a couple of other subroutines.

When I use a call inside an if statement I get an error:

> Expected Variable or Procedure, not Module.

Here's the call procedure:

```
Call schedule_3_day(shift1, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Employees"), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("3 Day Template"))
```

Here's the function to which it refers.

```
Sub schedule_3_day(ByRef sourcesheet As Worksheet, ByRef employeesheet As Worksheet, ByRef template As Worksheet)
```

On it's own, i.e. when it is a self contained subroutine, schedule_3_day works as intended. I am trying to alter it to pass user defined variables into it.

Comment: Have you named your modules?  This is the error message you get if you call a procedure in a module when both have the same name.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Please post your comment as an answer, so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @Daniel.  I don't normally post two sentence answers but you are correct, I should have posted this as an answer.  I have added a bit of background which may be useful to other readers.

Comment: @TonyDallimore +1 for the answer :)

Comment: @TonyDallimore I understand, I don't like to post 2 sentence answers either. And would also add more detail. :)

Answer (score 12):

**Background**

When Excel creates modules it names then `Module1`, `Module2` and so on.  This can get confusing if, like me, you divide your routines into sets: Global, Task1, Task2 and so on.

Not everyone seems to know you can rename Excel modules.  This is made obvious in Access where you are asked for a module's name.  For Excel you have to discover this facility for yourself.

Select the module, click F4 and the modules properties will appear in a floating window just as it does for a form. The only property is `Name` which you can change to anything that conforms to the rules for a variable name.  Using this facility I rename my modules: `Global`, `Task1`, `Task2` and so on, which allows me to easily identify the module I want to work on today.

**Limitation**

I believe you have encountered the one limitation with the choice of name for a module.

If I rename a module `Task1` then a sub, function, or global variable within that module named `Task1` is invisible from outside.

The error message "Expected Variable or Procedure, Not Module" is to be expected if the module containing `sub schedule_3_day(ByRef ...` is named `schedule3_day`.

Answer (score 1):

If the module and the macro have the same name do this:

module.macro

So if my module and macro are both called FreezeColumnFilter then the code would be:

FreezeColumnFilter.FreezeColumnFilter